# energy difference vs absolute energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

When dealing with determining the ground state energy of a system, people often say that it is better to know the energy difference rather than the absolute minimum energy. I understand that the absolute minimum energy depend on the model so the more complex your model, the lower or closer the energy you found to the true ground state energy.

But what do people refer to when they say energy difference here? Different between what energies exactly?

Comment: They are referring to the energy difference between electronic or vibrational states or between rotational states.  Energy in QM calculations must always be in reference to something.  Usually it is specified as the minimum of the PES for the lowest electronic state.  As you mentioned, absolute energies will depend on the method and choice of expansion, basis, etc.

Comment: Absolute energies returned from ab initio software is usually with reference to infinite separation of all particles which is usually hundreds of hartree away from the minimum energy of the PES so that it is a useless reference point.

Comment: The energy difference can also be from the bottom of the potential well, but being trapped at the bottom of the well is not an accessible state.

Comment: At the end is due to the fact that nothing has absolute zero energy, just a minimum. As far you are able to get or locate values versus the same reference, than you can compare them.

Comment: @Bertram Regard to your first comment: Let's say I use two different methods to calculate the electronic ground state energies. Then is it right for me to say that the energy differences here refer to the differences in energy I get from different geometry configurations? For example, I calculate it the ground state energy at bond distance of 1,2, and 3 Angstrom. I found that I get min energy occurred at 2 Angstrom on both method. Now, I will take the difference between the energies between 1 and 2 Angstrom and 3 and 2 Angstrom on both methods and compare?

Comment: @Alchimista am just trying to understand how can I calculate this energy difference that people tend to refer to. I understand that if you give me a Hamiltonian, I can discretize using some basis, then solve for the lowest eigenvalue. What value can I take as a reference point for me to calculate what people often refer to as energy difference? Thank you for your response!

Comment: @user102247 Yes the process you described would be reasonable.  As long as you are looking at the energy differences at different geometries within the same method.  And as you might expect there will be differences in the results depending on what method you are using.

Comment: @user102247 if you look for a technical answer be clearer in your question. The point is that you get different values, the difference is naturally there. It can be that whatever method is more or less accurate depending on the absolute energy, but this is already too technical. Perhaps I don't get your question. Conceptually, is like to graphically split AO in MO. The difference between the levels is in there.

Comment: Perhaps I got it. No one would ever state an energy difference for just the ground of a species being calculated. If done, it will be implicit there is a common reference for all cases treated the same way. This doesn't happen in quantum calculations only. Think about thermochemistry or thermodynamics. You can sort a table of H of formation for compounds. But you must have defined standard conditions, as well as what "formation" stands for.

Comment: To clarify, the meaning of "better to know the energy difference..." is more understandably "keep in mind that the energy of the minimum is rather a difference in energy versus some kind of reference". There is no difference to be calculated, it is just a statement that the value is not absolute.